# Equivalence of $\sigma$-algebras: generated by $[a,b]$ and $(-\infty,b]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Show that the $\sigma$-algebras generated by the collection of all intervals of the form $[a,b]\subset\Bbb R$ and by the collection of all the intervals of the form $(-\infty,b]\subset\Bbb R$ are equivalent.

Comment: Where did you come across this question? Why are you interested in the answer?

Comment: one of my homework question

Comment: Are you sure you've transcribed everything correctly? $[-\infty,b]$ isn't a subset of $\Bbb R,$ since $-\infty\notin\Bbb R.$

Comment: yes. it is a closed interval. @Cameron Buie

Comment: In that case, your text must have a misprint, or perhaps is using a strange convention

Comment: (−∞,b]⊂R isnt it correct? @Cameron Buie

Comment: Yes, *that's* correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: show that you can construct every type of generators from the other, using "allowed operations" in sigma algebras (countable unions, intersections,....).

Comment: I am new to probability. can you be more specific?

Comment: $[a,b]=\cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (a- 1/n,b]$, and $(a- 1/n,b]=(-\infty,b] \cap (-\infty,a- 1/n]^c$, so by definition of sigma algebra we have $\{ [a,b] / a,b \in \mathbb{R} \} \subset \sigma( \{(-\infty,b] / b \in \mathbb{R} \})$. By definition of generated sigma algebra then $\sigma (\{ [a,b] / a,b \in \mathbb{R} \} ) \subset \sigma( \{(-\infty,b] / b \in \mathbb{R} \})$. You can prove the other content with similar arguments and conclude the equality.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thank you, I corrected it.